# Fill all textarea with text without multiple sendkeys (loop)?

Tags: java, loops, selenium, while-loop

I have a problem, I have a form (angularJS) and this form has 10 textarea, right now I have 10 times, sendkes action, which makes code ugly :(

How can I find all mine textareas and pass a value only once?

Right now I have something like this:

```
 List<WebElement> allFormElements= driver.findElements(By.xpath("myPath"));
        allFormElements.size();
        System.out.println("Lets count all forms" +allFormElements);
        for (WebElement item : allFormElements) {
            if (item.getTagName().equals("textarea"))
           item.sendKeys("testing values");
        }
```

Thakns

Comment: You can use By.Selector("textarea") equivalent in java instead of xpath to get all the text area elements in page. If all the textarea are inside same form you can modify selector to be "form textarea" or if form have id you can do "form#id textarea" , etc.

Comment: You can write javascript and set value with loop but faster. But maybe you need to add some controls if field is disabled or readonly, mayde check max length of textarea...

Comment: I don’t think that this is possible. Iterating through all the textareas with for is just fine.

Comment: @Peter : What's wrong with the existing code ? what does `allFormElements.size();` return ?

Comment: @cruisepandey, return 15 (total amount of textareas)

Comment: @PeterPavlov : in OP you have mentioned `and this form has 10 textarea` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me fine!

```
List<WebElement> allInputFields = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("cm-edit-request-form dx-text-area textarea"));
        if(allInputFields.size()!=0){
            for(WebElement allInputFieldsElement:allInputFields){
                if(allInputFieldsElement.isEnabled()) {
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((allInputFieldsElement)));
                    allInputFieldsElement.sendKeys("Automation text" + uuid);
                }
            }
```

Comment: where: size()!=0, ignoring all HIDDEN fields